# A parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, is invoked via document.write warning

Tags: javascript

When I look at my site's console, I see in Chrome the following warning:

> A parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, `https://t1.daumcdn.net/cssjs/common/cts/vr200/dcts.js`, is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details.

my page code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 //<![CDATA[ 
 var DaumConversionDctSv="type=M,orderID=,amount="; 
 var DaumConversionAccountID="Ki7kLa_84SUcid7XE.GR4A00"; 
 if(typeof DaumConversionScriptLoaded=="undefined"&&location.protocol!="file:"){ 
    var DaumConversionScriptLoaded=true; 
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript%20type%3D%22text/javas"+"cript%22%20src%3D%22"+(location.protocol=="https:"?"https":"http")+"%3A//t1.daumcdn.net/cssjs/common/cts/vr200/dcts.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E")); 
 } 
 //]]> 
</script>

    <script>
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
                (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

        ga('create', 'UA-141511041-1', 'auto');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
```

Can anyone help please to fix this warning? Thank you.

Comment: Did you go to the link in the warning message?

Comment: If this is something a third-party provider told you to put in your script to use their service, you should contact them to find out how to do it correctly in modern browsers.

Comment: BTW, `//<![CDATA[ ` has not been needed in scripts for decades.

Answer (score -1):

**Not sure but you can try the following options:**

> Load the script asynchronously: You can use the async attribute to
> load the script asynchronously, which means that the script will be
> executed as soon as it is available, without blocking the parser. To
> do this, you can add the async attribute to the script tag in the head tag:

```
<script src="https://t1.daumcdn.net/cssjs/common/cts/vr200/dcts.js" async></script>
```

> Defer the script: You can use the defer attribute to defer the
> execution of the script until the page has finished parsing. To do
> this, you can add the defer attribute to the script tag in the head tag:

```
<script src="https://t1.daumcdn.net/cssjs/common/cts/vr200/dcts.js" defer></script>
```

> Place the script at the bottom of the page: You can place the script
> at the bottom of the page, just before the closing  tag, to
> ensure that the script is loaded after the page has finished parsing.
> This will prevent the script from blocking the parser.

Comment: who are you quoting here?